# Shell script exec mysql procedure from external file with argument from command line

Tags: mysql, linux, sh

I have a sh script where I connect to mysql and try to execute a stored procedure saved in a local file.

```
tblName="table${k}"
mysql -h 10.0.0.1 --user=username --password=password 
      -e "use db_test; set @tableName=${tblName}; source query.sql;"
```

and the file query.sql:

```
set @str = concat('create table ', @tableName, ' (
 id int not null,
 ....
);');
prepare stmt from @str;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

The mysql command is in a for loop, "k" is an index. I want to create a table with the name taken from the tableName variable. The problem is that I receive an error as:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'table1' in 'field list'
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'table2' in 'field list'
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'table3' in 'field list'
...
```

I'm a bit confusing because "table1" is a table name and not a column. What I am doing wrong? I found a lot of examples using this approach, but I don't know why for me it not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command:

```
set @tableName=${tblName}
```

requires tablename to be enclosed in ''.

To fix do:

```
set @tableName='${tblName}'
```

Testing this in MySQL shell shows the problem:

```
mysql> set @tableName=table1;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'table1' in 'field list'
mysql> set @tableName='table1';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```